# Installing php on CentOS using Terminal

Tags: php, linux, bash, centos

I am very new to all of this so please forgive my ignorance. I have a VPS running CentOS 6 and Plesk. I am trying to install a new version of PHP (current version is 5.3) using the following tutorial http://kb.parallels.com/en/118378

I use the command `wget http://uk1.php.net/get/php-5.4.27.tar.gz/from/this/mirror` which downloads the file php-5.4.27.tar.gz but saves it to 'mirror'

If I then try to access 'mirror' using `cd mirror` I get a message stating `-bash: cd: mirror: Not a directory`. I have also tried `cd /mirror`, `cd /mirror/` and `cd /mirror/`.

I am getting nowhere with this so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is mirror a directory?  or anything else?

Comment: Well, it's presumably still a gzipped tar file, so try `tar -xzf mirror`

Comment: I am assuming it's a directory, to be honest, I don't want the gz file to download to the mirror directory.

Comment: `wget http://uk1.php.net/get/php-5.4.27.tar.gz/from/this/mirror -O php-5.4.27.tar.gz` should download directly to that location.

Comment: Thanks Wooble that worked. I have a whole other host of problems now though as the next bit of the tutorial throws up a load of errors. I'll keep going. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is rename mirror to php-5.4.27.tar.gz , extract it and then cd to the directory.

1. mv mirror php-5.4.27.tar.gz
2. tar xvf php-5.4.27.tar.gz
3. cd php-5.4.27